# How to assign custom CSS class to arbitrary arbitrary rows of h:dataTable?

Tags: css, jsf, datatable

I'm trying to assign a specific CSS class to specific rows of my `<h:dataTable>`. Is there some way to access and cutomize the resulting table rows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bind the `rowClasses` attribute to a bean property which returns the desired string of CSS classes.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.list}" rowClasses="#{bean.rowClasses}">
```

with e.g.

```
public String getRowClasses() {
    StringBuilder rowClasses = new StringBuilder();
    for (Item item : list) {
        if (rowClasses.length() > 0) rowClasses.append(",");
        rowClasses.append(item.getRowClass());
    }
    return rowClasses.toString();
}
```

---

**Update** to clarify, this way you have full programmatic control over the `rowClasses` string. Note that the above is just a kickoff example, it doesn't necessarily need to be obtained by `Item#getRowClass()` or so. You can even do it in a simple for loop with a counter.

E.g.

```
public String getRowClasses() {
    StringBuilder rowClasses = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (rowClasses.length() > 0) rowClasses.append(",");
        rowClasses.append(selected.contains(i) ? "selected" : "none");
    }
    return rowClasses.toString();
}
```

where `selected` is a `List<Integer>`. If it contains 1, 2 and 5, then the returned string will look like as follows for a list of 10 items:

```
none,selected,selected,none,none,selected,none,none,none,none
```

Comment: Thank you BalusC, but I meant assign a specific class to a single specific row: e.g. assign CSS class "redRow" to 3rd row. rowClasses let me specify a repeating schema for all rows.

Comment: Just let the 3rd item return `redRow` on `getRowClass()`. Or use a counter and append `redRow` on 3rd item. Do you understand the point of the given answer anyway?

Answer (score 1):

I like @BalusC suggestion. If you want a second alternative, you can do this easily with javascript/JQuery.

With JQuery you can do it like this

(Note, this is just an example. I haven't tested it, and there is probably a better way of doing it)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var counter = 0;
  $('#myTable').each(function() {
      counter = counter + 1;
      if(counter==3) {
        $(this).addClass('redRow');
        return;
      }
    
  });
}
```

Comment: Just `$('#myTable tbody tr:eq(2)').addClass('redRow')` is also doable.